# change text using arrays and button next

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the elements on the array contenidoHistoria and actually created this function that responds to an event listener. But is only showing me the first element of the array and not the other elements as i press the button

```js
var botonSiguiente = document.createElement('button')
botonSiguiente.setAttribute('id', 'siguiente')
botonSiguiente.innerText = 'Siguiente'
optionButtons = document.getElementById('option-buttons').appendChild(botonSiguiente)
document.getElementById('siguiente').addEventListener('click', siguiente, true)

//creating a 'sguiente' button event
var siguiente = function() {
var no_of_clicks = 0
//array that contains the infomration to pass everytime the button is clicked
var contenidoHistoria = ['texto 1', 'texto 2', 'texto 3', 'texto 4', 'texto 5']
var base = document.getElementById('base');
    base.innerHTML = `<p> ${contenidoHistoria[no_of_clicks]}</p>`
no_of_clicks == (contenidoHistoria.length - 1) ? no_of_clicks = 0 : no_of_clicks = no_of_clicks + 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define `no_of_clicks` every time the function `siguiente` is run, so it is reset to `0` on every click. If you take `no_of_clicks` out of the function, it will work as you intend. Also, it's a better practice to use `let` and `const` rather than using `var` as it prevents hoisting. I also took out `contenidoHistoria` outside of the function as well since it is also not something you need to create every time the function is run. :

```js
let no_of_clicks = 0
//array that contains the infomration to pass everytime the button is clicked
const contenidoHistoria = ['texto 1', 'texto 2', 'texto 3', 'texto 4', 'texto 5']

const siguiente = function() {
  const base = document.getElementById('base');
  base.innerHTML = `<p> ${contenidoHistoria[no_of_clicks]}</p>`
  no_of_clicks == (contenidoHistoria.length - 1) ? no_of_clicks = 0 : no_of_clicks = no_of_clicks + 1;

}
```